# Prime numbers between two given positive integers

Tags: python, nested-loops

This is the program for finding prime numbers in a specific range.
Instead of getting prime numbers, I am getting the prime numbers repeating itself for a number of times.

This is a program for finding prime numbers in a specific range.

```py
start = 25
end = 50

print(f"The prime numbers from {start} to {end} are :  ")

for num in range(start, end+1):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                break
            else:
                print(num)
```

Expected output:

```
Prime numbers between 25 and 50 are:
29
31
37
41
43
47
```

Comment: Your program will work if you reduce the indentation on the `else:` and the `print` by one level, assuming you now have them under the `if`.

Comment: Unless you want to implement this yourself, you could easily use the `sympy` module's `isprime` function. It has a time complexity of O(sqrt(n)) and an auxiliary space of O(1).

Answer (score 1):

This is because, the `if else` block under `for i in range(2, num)` is executed multiple times until the for loop breaks out.

Every time the `if` condition is evaluated to false, the `else` block is executed, and that happens multiple times

And therefore the same number is printed multiple times

To rectify this, you will have to move the print statement somewhere out of the `for loop`

```py
start = 25
end = 50

print(f"The prime numbers from {start} to {end} are :  ")

for num in range(start, end+1):
    if num > 1:
        is_prime = True
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break

        if is_prime:
            print(num)
```

Comment: Greatly explained !

Answer (score 0):

One of the keys of programming is breaking things down into smaller problems. While your approach to calculating primes is inefficient, it can be effective. Your code would be easier to understand if this were broken out into a separate function.

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
  for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
    if n % i == 0:
      return False
  return True
```

Having done this:

```
>>> print(
...   *(x 
...     for x in range(20, 51) 
...     if is_prime(x)), 
...   sep='\n', end='\n'
... )
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
```

Anyone working with primes should probably read about the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the sieve or Eratosthenes to the range of numbers:

```
def primesBetween(a,b):
    sieve = [1]*(b-a+1)
    p2, p, inc = 4, 2, 1
    while p2 <= b:
        start = (-a)%p if p2 < a else p2-a 
        sieve[start::p]  = (len(sieve)-start+p-1)//p * [0]
        p,inc = p+inc, 2
        p2    = p * p
    return [n for n,isPrime in enumerate(sieve,a) if isPrime]
```

output:

```
print(primesBetween(100,200))
[101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 
 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199]
```